# How to traverse character elements of *const char pointer in Rust?

Tags: pointers, rust

I'm new to Rust programing and I have a bit of difficulty when this language is different from C Example, I have a C function as follows:

```
bool check(char* data, int size){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if( data[i] != 0x00){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

How can I convert this function to Rust? I tried it like C, but it has Errors :((

Comment: What is `data`? It is a zero-terminated character string? If yes, how did you create it? Rust does not have zero-terminated character strings. Not all concepts of C/C++ are transferrable to Rust; some need rethinking of the code. This might be one of them.

Comment: *"I tried it like C, but it has Errors"* - please show your attempt and the errors you get.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I assume that you want to use as little `unsafe` code as possible. Otherwise there really isn't any reason to use Rust in the first place, as you forfeit all the advantages it brings you.

Depending on what `data` represents, there are multiple ways to transfer this to Rust.

First off: Using pointer and length as two separate arguments is not possible in Rust without `unsafe`. It has the same concept, though; it's called [`slices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html). A slice is exactly the same as a pointer-size combination, just that the compiler understands it and checks it for correctness at compile time.

That said, a `char*` in C could actually be one of four things. Each of those things map to different types in Rust:

- Binary data whose deallocation is taken care of somewhere else (in Rust terms: **borrowed data**)

  - maps to `&[u8]`, a **slice**. The actual content of the slice is:

    - the address of the data as `*u8` (hidden from the user)
    - the length of the data as `usize`
- Binary data that has to be deallocated within this function after using it (in Rust terms: **owned data**)

  - maps to `Vec<u8>`; as soon as it goes out of scope the data is deleted
  - actual content is:

    - the address of the data as `*u8` (hidden from the user)
    - the length of the data as `usize`
    - the size of the allocation as `usize`. This allows for efficient `push()`/`pop()` operations. It is guaranteed that the length of the data does not exceed the size of the allocation.
- A string whose deallocation is taken care of somewhere else (in Rust terms: a **borrowed string**)

  - maps to `&str`, a so called **string slice**.
  - This is identical to `&[u8]` with the additional **compile time guarantee** that it contains valid UTF-8 data.
- A string that has to be deallocated within this function after using it (in Rust terms: an **owned string**)

  - maps to `String`
  - same as `Vec<u8>` with the additional **compile time guarantee** that it contains valid UTF-8 data.

You can create `&[u8]` references from `Vec<u8>`'s and `&str` references from `String`s.

---

Now this is the point where I have to make an assumption. Because the function that you posted checks if all of the elements of `data` are zero, and returns `false` if if finds a non-zero element, I assume the content of `data` is binary data. And because your function does not contain a `free` call, I assume it is **borrowed data**.

With that knowledge, this is how the given function would translate to Rust:

```rust
fn check(data: &[u8]) -> bool {
    for d in data {
        if *d != 0x00 {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}

fn main() {
    let x = vec![0, 0, 0];
    println!("Check {:?}: {}", x, check(&x));

    let y = vec![0, 1, 0];
    println!("Check {:?}: {}", y, check(&y));
}
```

```
Check [0, 0, 0]: true
Check [0, 1, 0]: false
```

This is quite a direct translation; it's not really idiomatic to use `for` loops a lot in Rust. Good Rust code is mostly iterator based; iterators are most of the time zero-cost abstraction that can get compiled **very** efficiently.

This is how your code would look like if rewritten based on iterators:

```rust
fn check(data: &[u8]) -> bool {
    data.iter().all(|el| *el == 0x00)
}

fn main() {
    let x = vec![0, 0, 0];
    println!("Check {:?}: {}", x, check(&x));

    let y = vec![0, 1, 0];
    println!("Check {:?}: {}", y, check(&y));
}
```

```
Check [0, 0, 0]: true
Check [0, 1, 0]: false
```

The reason this is more idiomatic is that it's a lot easier to read for someone who hasn't written it. It clearly says "return true if all elements are equal to zero". The `for` based code needs a second to think about to understand if its "all elements are zero", "any element is zero", "all elements are non-zero" or "any element is non-zero".

Note that both versions compile to the [exact same bytecode](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/4GfTdaxdv).

Also note that, unlike the C version, the Rust borrow checker guarantees **at compile time** that `data` is valid. It's impossible in Rust (without `unsafe`) to produce a double free, a use-after-free, an out-of-bounds array access or **any** other kind of undefined behaviour that would cause memory corruption.

This is also the reason why Rust doesn't do pointers without `unsafe` - it needs the length of the data to check out-of-bounds errors at runtime. That means, accessing data via `[]` operator is a little more costly in Rust (as it does perform an out-of-bounds check every time), which is the reason why iterator based programming is a thing. Iterators can iterate over data a lot more efficient than directly accessing it via `[]` operators.